# Two way binding in custom directive with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I basically have a list of items that are stored as an array of objects. Some of these items are "children" of others. This is denoted by a "parentid" setting in each object. This only means that I want to display children as a nested list within the parent.

So, I start by iterating through the array and find one with no parent. When I find it, I call a directive that takes that ID and then again iterates through the main array and finds any item whose parentID is identical to the one in question and displays it. There can be multiple levels of children so that the directive is called recursively.

This works fine and displays all of the children, but I want to be able to select any one of these items and see that ID or object at the top level. This is not working. I pass a variable into each directive with two way binding but no parent is ever updated. I understand the primitive problem and I am passing an object but that is not working. I think that I need to do something with the repeats, but I am not sure what. I do not think transclusion is the issue.

In the demo below, I need to display the updated var3 variable whenever I click on an item.

Initial HTML

```
<div>{{var3}}</div>
<div>
    <my-directive var1="item1"
                  var2="item2"
                  var3="item3">
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Directive

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

    function structureContent($templateRequest, $compile)
    {   return {
            restrict : 'E',

            scope:{
                var1:'=',
                var2:'@',
                var3:'='
            },

            controller : ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs",

                function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                }
            ],

            link : function(scope, element, attrs){

                scope.$watch('worksheet', 

                    function(){

                        $templateRequest("myTemplate.html").then(function(html){
                            var template = angular.element(html);
                            element.html(template);
                            $compile(template)(scope);
                        });

                    }, true 
                );
            }
        }
    }; 
})();
```

Directive HTML

```
<div>
    <div ng-click="var3=thisItem.itemid;">(Display  item)    </div>
    // var3 is what I want to be able to pull out at the top level
</div>


<div ng-repeat="thisObj in myArray | orderBy:'order' track by thisObj.itemid" 
    ng-switch on="thisObj.type_id" 
    ng-if="thisObj.content.parentid==thisItem.itemid" 
    class="subSection" >


    <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <my-directive var1="{{var1}}"
                         var2="var2"
                         var3="var3">
        </my-directive>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @JoshuaFoxworth description is confusing, could you please explain it little more detailed taking some sample data.

Comment: So, I may have solved this by accident. I had set the initial value of the item I want to pass up is an empty object. Apparently, this doesn't work and there is still an indexing problem. It started working after I populated the variable appropriately. Was that the case? Is an empty object not enough?